# Why is this printf cmd failing

Tags: printf

```
find . -name '.git' -exec printf %q "'{}'"  \; ;
printf: illegal format character q
```

It seems the problem is that the printf being called is not bashes builtin printf Is there any way to use builtin printf ?

Comment: Did you see 'man' page for printf? Mine says the printf handles " all C format specifications ending with one of diouxXfeEgGcs." The '%q' not mentioned...

Comment: it is a bash builtin param on osx or linux help printf lists it

Comment: I really doubt `find` will call an internal `bash` command, it's certainly the external command. If you want to use internal command, call bash and give it an inline script to execute printf: ` find . -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c "printf %q\\\\n {}" \;`

Comment: `find -exec` (and also `xargs`) will not be able to call shell builtins, they can only call external utilities. The below answer which execs another shell is a good (the best?) way to call the shell builtin for `printf`, instead of an external utility like `/usr/bin/printf`.

Comment: @Aeronautix this is certainly an acceptable answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `bash` and give it an inline script to invoke `printf`:

```
 find . -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c "printf %q\\\\n {}" \;
```